# How do I connect a android app to a mysql database that is not local?

Tags: java, android, mysql

Hey I have found plenty of tutorials for people who are making the databases on their own computer but I am trying to connect to one that is not local

```
private class SignUpA extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = "jbdc:mysql://mywbdb.cjymdxzuzy46.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mysql";
        String dbName = "profiles";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Properties userInfo = new Properties();
        userInfo.put("user", "user");
        userInfo.put("password", "pass");

        try {

            Class.forName(driver);

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName,
                    userInfo);
            CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
            Toast tost = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            tost.show();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have imported the jdbc library and have tried using the DriverManager.registerDriver also but it still crashed.Also I changed the url and the username and password for obvious reasons. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Also have tried  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
Side Note: I know that apps are easily cracked and my database could be accessed very easily but at this point I am just trying to get it to work

Comment: Do you have the mysql connector in your libs folder?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't normally expose a mysql database to the Internet like that - your just asking to be hacked.  Typically you would write a Web Service and expose that instead.  Then your Android app would make calls to the Web Service to update the database.

Comment: Yeah I know but right now I am just trying to get it to connect, if I do decide to release to the public then I will do it the secure way lol

Comment: but you already told the world a server address and possibly a username and password - not trying to be an ass but I seriously think the answer to this question is "don't do that!"

Comment: I changed the username, password and server address, unless I changed it to someone else's server address you shouldn't be able to do anything with it

Comment: You could trying using an sqlite database if you just need to store data locally too.  There's also key-value stores built for the web such as couchdb which are good if you need to share state.

Comment: This is for a school project and eventually I will need to be able to show it off while my phone/tablet is connected to my schools network, so I am not trying to store it locally.